# In c++, `expressions` are allowed in global scope only to initialize global objects. Where can I find this in the Standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The commented out *expression* below doesn't compile, because it is in the global scope. But where in the C++ Standard do I find something that relates to this restriction? As I recall, *expressions* are allowed in global scope only to initialize global objects. I have already looked into **Chapter 5 Expressions**, to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
//std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);


int main()
{
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
}
```

Comment: I think a better way of saying this is that "only declaration statements are allowed at namespace scope".

Comment: @KerrekSB "only declarations" is more like it. "declaration statements" is a limited subset of declarations

Comment: @T.C.: Yes, right. I was confused about that before. Thanks.

Comment: It's easy enough to get around this with a global like so: `int i = (std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield), 0);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is all going down to **3.5 Program and linkage**:

> 1) A program consists of one or more translation units (Clause 2) linked together. A translation unit consists
>   of a sequence of declarations.
>   *translation-unit:
>
>   declaration-seq opt*

Following that syntax description you'll find what is allowed in a *declaration-seq* and what is allowed in each *declaration*. And as can be seen a regular *statement* is not allowed at *translation-unit* level.