# Unknown type name error when inserting into unordered_map

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unordered-map

I have a single file called *main.cpp* where I am trying to declare an `unordered_map` as shown below.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<int>> firstSets;
```

I then try to insert a new (key, value) pair into the map as follows.

```
std::string decl = "decl";
std::set<int> declFirstSet = {VOID_TOK, INT_TOK, FLOAT_TOK, BOOL_TOK};
firstSets[decl] = declFirstSet;
```

When I do this I get the following compiler error.

> C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
>
> firstSets[decl] = declFirstSet;
>
> size of array has non-integer type 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string')
>
> firstSets[decl] = declFirstSet;

So it seems to think I am declaring 'firstSets' when I am actually tring to insert into it. And it seems to treat 'firstSets' as an array instead of an `unordered_map`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are those declarations/expression at global scope (outside of a function)?

Comment: Yes. @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: Put the insert inside main and it should work

Comment: You can't have expressions in global scope. `firstSets[decl] = declFirstSet;` needs to be inside a function. You could also initialize it using the constructor when you define it.

Comment: ok that worked, thanks. Why can't you have expressions at the global scope?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460505/in-c-expressions-are-allowed-in-global-scope-only-to-initialize-global-obje).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `std::make_pair` is wrong. To get closer you need a `std::set<int>` instead of the `std::set`.

But what you really want is to just let to compiler make it for you:

```cpp
    firstSets.insert(std::make_pair(decl, declFirstSet));
```

or use an easier syntax:

```cpp
    firstSets[decl] = declFirstSet;
```

**EDIT AFTER UNDERSTANDING THE PROBLEM**
On the otherhand, you want `firstSets` to come with initial content you can reorder the declarations:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

std::string decl{"decl"};
std::set<int> declFirstSet{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<int>> firstSets{{decl, declFirstSet}};

int main() {}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the changes you have suggested. @Bo R

Comment: My test of you code looke like this `#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<int>> firstSets;
    std::string decl = "decl";
    std::set<int> declFirstSet = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    firstSets[decl] = declFirstSet;
}` Since you're not show all the code the the problem is likely earlier in the source code of macros involing `VOID_TOK` and the other values, or a missing header. Hard to tell.

Comment: My code is not in a main function, it is at the global scope. I will update to show more detailed code. @Bo R

Comment: @TomFinet, I know understand the problem. You *cannot* have an expression in a scope outside of a function. Thus `firstSets[decl] = declFirstSet;` is being tried as a declaration (which it is not) by the compiler. Having `void somefunctionname() { firstSets[decl] = declFirstSet; }` is the best you can do.

Comment: The "easier" syntax has different semantics. That might lead to subtle bugs if he thinks they do exactly the same thing...

Comment: True @vmp, agreed, but in this case not really part of the original problem as we've both found out.

Comment: thats why I mentioned, It could lead him to future problems if he simply start using the `[]` way (which is the one I always use and got surprised when found out that insert did things differently) without being aware of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it is not working, but you don't need to call make_pair...
Changing the insertion line to:

```
firstSets.insert({decl, declFirstSet});
```

Should solve your problem.

Here would be a full code example:

```
#include <set>
#include<string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<int>> firstSets;
    set<int> s = { 1, 2, 3 };
    firstSets.insert({ "key", s });   
}
```

But seems like you want them declared in global scope, so you would initialize like the following code:

```
#include <set>
#include<string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

set<int> s1 = { 1, 2, 3 }, s2 = { 4, 5, 6 };
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<int>> firstSets{ {"key1", s1}, {"key2", s2}};
int main()
{
}
```

Comment: The error still persists. It still says: "unknown type name 'firstSets' " and "cannot use dot operator on a type". @vmp

Comment: @vmp, you must include `<string>` in you example.

Comment: oh, yeah... visual studio seems to add it under the hood, will fix that!